# Add class to parent div with specific input

Tags: jquery

I have following situation:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="first_name">
    First name
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="first_name" type="text" value="rybka">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have input's id. I want to add class to div with "control-group" class and input with the specified id. What if the perfect way to do this?

Edit:

Thanks for all answers I used that solution:

```
$(".control-group:has(#specificId)").addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: hey you should closest in place of has to inhance the performance see my answer for this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector at this context,

```
$(".control-group:has(#specificId)").addClass('yourClass');
```

Or you can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) too

```
$("#specificId").closest(".control-group").addClass('yourClass');
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I used your solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to get all parent elements and [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to add class to element. Try this:

```
$("#first_name").parents(".control-group").addClass("testClass");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/nwa9jnfc/1/)**

Comment: +1, though you don't need those element names in the selectors: `$("#first_name").parents(".control-group")`

Answer (score 1):

i have created jsfiddle for your problem and you should **closest** in place of **has**.
**closest** works faster then **has** method see the code and working jsfiddle for it.

code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.time("has")
    $(".control-group:has(#first_name)").addClass('yourClass');
    console.timeEnd("has")

    console.time("closest")
    $("#specificId").closest(".control-group").addClass('yourClass');
    console.timeEnd("closest")

});
```

working jsfiddle example:-http://jsfiddle.net/dwxmjkb3/13/

see the result on console.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No perfect way but many ways to do this. I will assume you want to add the class that was added in the input.

```
$('input').change(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass('someclass');
});
```

This would go all the way back to the top parent and will add the class.